# Accidentally overwrote an existing branch

Tags: eclipse, svn, branch

I created a new branch from trunk( intended as Version 1.1.5.0) and incorrectly named/pointed the branch to an existing branch ( Version 1.1.0.5) in my SVN repository.  Can I undo this?  I correctly created a new branch from trunk as intended afterwards but now branch 1.1.5.0 and 1.1.0.5 are identical.  Would it better to create a new project in eclipse and grab a copy of the production files (which is at Version 1.1.0.5) and commit it to the correct branch? [Branch Heirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSf7M.png)

Comment: Undo means in SVN to revert changes from a revision. So yes, it is possible with svn revert

Comment: There's no revision history.  I overwrote the branch when I selected my Trunk and went to TEAM-Branch/Tag and typed in an existing branch in the Copy to URL field under the Repository section instead of creating a new branch.  The TEAM - Revert option says there's no changes to revert to.

Comment: Maybe the branch shows no revision history, but the repository does